# Hibernate hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create/update/validate doesn't work for correctly for custom dialects?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I recently upgrade Hibernate from version 3.3.x to 3.6.4. In version 3.3.x validateSchema (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate) works correctly.

In version 3.6.x validation is broken (tested for 3.6.4 and 3.6.7 as well). **The issue is relevant only for field type text.**

I redefined the SQL type in my dialect e.g.

```
public class SQLServer2000UnicodeDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

public SQLServer2000UnicodeDialect(){
    super();

    // Use Unicode Characters
    ...
    registerColumnType( Types.CLOB, "ntext" );
    ...
}
```

}

But during validation, hibernate use original SQL types instead of customized!

> Wrong column type in db.dbo.table_name for column a_column. Found:
>   ntext, expected: text

It looks like a bug, but not sure if it is. Maybe I'm missing something in configuration?

P.S. **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create/update** doesn't works correctly also!

P.P.S. My XML mapping configuration:

```
<property name="propName" type="text" column="a_column"/>
```

Comment: During validation of what, "hibernate use original SQL types instead of customized"?

Comment: Configuration.validateSchema() or hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create/update/validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit strange, but hibernate somewhere in versions 3.4-3.6 changed binding of "text" mapping (actually [hibernate have two types of mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes) for long strings: clob and text).

In version 3.3 both mapping (clob and text) were mapped to `Types.CLOB`.

In version 3.6 you have to provide separate mapping for text and for clob. Fixing my dialect as shown below solved my issue:

```
public class SQLServer2000UnicodeDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

    public SQLServer2000UnicodeDialect(){
        super();
        ...
        registerColumnType( Types.CLOB, "ntext" );
        registerColumnType( Types.LONGVARCHAR, "ntext" );

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=941781&highlight=sqlserver+dialect+unicode) It looks like something similar. And the author claims it is working. And [this](http://blog.tremend.ro/2007/05/23/hibernate-utf-8-and-sql-server-2005/).

As to your question, I suspect that while validation your class is somehow left out. Did you wire up your class properly and is JAR in the classpath etc?

This message :

```
Found: ntext, expected: text
```

tells me that you have a property of type `ntext` somewhere. What I believe you should be doing is : to continue using hibernate types in your schema, and let hibernate handle converting the types into the database specific type using the dialect. Do not use custom types in XML mapping files.